# Using Stellar for a non-financial private network

Tags: stellar-core

I'm new to Stellar and this community. I want to create a decentralized network for information sharing. Essentially a distributed database with data validation using blockchain. I have looked into Hyperledger Fabric before for such a task but deemed SCP to be more fitting for my needs.

My question is, could I use Stellar-Core for such a task? Namely, is creating a completely separate private network with custom data types possible? All of the information out there I found talks about private networks in terms of financial transactions and account registrations with the (private) network, which makes me think that financial transactions are built-in/intrinsic to Stellar-Core. If not, how can I create this network for such far-fetched purpose? And what is the difference between Stellar-Core and Stellar SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar has the possibility to store key-value pairs in each account. This might be a starting point for you. To know if you could use stellar for your purposes it would be good to have more information.

Comment: For example, user login events, duration, hashed passwords... etc

Comment: Yes you can do that, if you want more details how to do that, you can send me a private message